# Optimizing query for large table with `rand()` ordering

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a MySQL database running for a multiplayer game server and I've been trying to identify a performance bottleneck. I got the slow query logs and the slowest queries by time are like this (the matchmaking system):

```
select `accountID` from GameAccountProfile where `active`=1 and 
`lastActiveTime`<1482549810 and `inTutorial`=0 and `defenseRating`>0 and
`league`=4 and `protectedPeriod`>1482550190 and `lastActiveTime`>1481945090 and
`accountID`!=986702 and `accountID`!=10 and `accountID`!=10 and
`accountID`!=463126 and `accountID`!=184374 and `defenseRating`>=3.3530639 and
`defenseRating`<=6.2271186 and `level`>=-8 and `level`<=2
order by rand() limit 1;
```

There are currently about 1.3 million rows in this table. I read that the `rand()` sorting may be a serious performance hit and when I ran an `explain` on it in MySQL Workshop on the query, it did highlight it in red as being a performance hit.

Also, I realized that the only index for any of these where conditions is on the account ID column. I'm considering adding a composite index on the "active", "inTutorial", "level", and "league" columns as they don't change often (arranged starting with the least often changed).

How can I get a random account ID with these conditions without using `rand()` in an order clause? I need to ensure all accounts get targeted equally but `rand()` seems to be a clear performance hit.

Is there any other way I can improve the performance of this query?

Comment: There are many good questions and articles out there about this topic... here are two from SO just as FYI in case you find methods mentioned (even in unaccepted other answers per each question).... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function

Comment: can you add something like this **WHERE [your conditions] AND [id or accountID] >= rand()*maxid LIMIT1;** where maxid can be a old id so you not must get the actual maxid every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way to do `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`, but [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random) has several suggestions.  Some depend on `AUTO_INCREMENT`, some based on an extra column.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want one it's easy. Just choose a random offset and get that one. It's very fast and because you don't need to sort the table at all:

```
$total = query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GameAccountProfile WHERE blah");
$offset = rand(0, $total-1);
$id = query("SELECT accountID FROM GameAccountProfile WHERE blah LIMIT $offset, 1");
```